# HTML email text vertical align

Tags: html, email, text, alignment

I am currently have an issue with strange (well, html emails...) vertical display and it drives me nuts.

Basicly what I have is table: text on the left and image on the right. The problem is that text is vertical aligned to top.I have tried `valign="middle"` , css `vertical-align:middle;` and even `line-height:value;` nothing helps. The image is basicly in the top of that TD (TD height is same height like image's)

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="header">
<tr>    
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-family: tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color: #898989;letter-spacing: 2px;">
<strong>Text field</strong>
<img src="link_to_image.jpg" style="display:block;" align="right" valign="bottom" width="230" height="49" alt="Logo">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to make image and text in the same TD, else image has space between another image bellow this one.

Have anyone else encountered similar problem? Any ideas?

Regards,
Baseckas

Comment: Is dividing the td into two cols not an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it to work in a browser, but given that it is an html-email, you have to divide your table cell in to two columns and have one column the text and another colomn image. That is the only way Outlook will interpret it correctly. You may try surronding the image tag in a div, but that again has flaws for outlook.

Comment: Adding div for text, gives more vertical space (what I do not need), neither padding or margin helps. The reason I have started this deep workarround is Outlook (because of the space between images). Thing is, that this alingment must be prescise, because that image is part of the image bellow. Splitting table cell into two, messes it up what I am trying to avoid in the first place. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: If dividing td in to two cols messes the things up, then there is something other wrong in your code. dividing the td into 2 cols is the only way to go afaic

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will look into it. Atleast now I'll know the way to work in.

Comment: This is just another sad episode in the world of HTML E-mails. The current state of affairs is even worse than it was at the height of the browser wars, because no script can help you fix things now. IMHO, the Outlook developers deserve some decent slapping around for reinstating the horrible Word rendering engine. On topic: the two-column table did the trick for me, but I secretly still hope to find another, less laborous way.